# Spacemacs using the mouse to copy paste

Tags: spacemacs

I quite often use the mouse to highlight text and then press `cmd-c` (Osx) to copy the highlighted text. However it seems that the cursor is not updated when I do this and so instead of copying the highlighted text to the register it copies from current cursor position to end of where I highlighted. What am I doing wrong? I dont want to keep remembering to click before select to move the cursor.

I am using evilmode.

Answer (score 13):

Put

```
(xterm-mouse-mode -1)
```

under user-config in your .spacemacs file should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this isnt the problem. I'll have to try more accurately recreate this.

Comment: This is by far the simplest solution I have found.. thank you.

Comment: Thanks that's what I was looking for :)

Comment: WOW THANKS! took me forever.

Comment: The only user-config there is in my .spacemacs file is a function def