# spacemacs does not let me highlight with mouse and (command+c) copy to clipboard

Tags: macos, emacs, spacemacs

I am using spacemacs with default settings in vim mode, in terminal on macOS Sierra.

In the shell or other terminal applications, I often highlight text with the mouse and then (command+c) copy it to the system clipboard, from which I then (command+v) paste it somewhere else. I often do this with filepaths output by `pwd` for example.

This highlighting and copy-pasting worked for me in emacs before I installed spacemacs. But after installing spacemacs, when I hit (command+c) after highlighting with the mouse, my computer makes the *dun* sound it does when input is not understood, and the highlighted text is not copied to clipboard.

I have also tried highlighting the text using the visual mode commands (v, move cursor, then command+c) to highlight and copy, but the result is the same i.e. doesn't work.

In spacemacs, how can I copy to system clipboard in order to paste in another application? Is there some terminal setting that I need to adjust?

I am liking spacemacs, but this has been an issue for me as I the need to copy text from the editor seems to occur regularly in my workflow.

Comment: Do you have the osx layer installed?

Comment: I have added `osx` to the `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers` list of my `~/.spacemacs` file, as instructed in the 'spacemacs osx layer' [install documentation](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Bos/osx#install). Still cannot seem to copy to clipboard.

Comment: It started to do that on my machine..  frustrating

Comment: try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37631440/spacemacs-using-the-mouse-to-copy-paste